# Malformed string from character string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a simple character string:

```
y <- "Location 433900E 387200N, Lat 53.381 Lon -1.490, 131 metres amsl"
```

When I perform regex capture on it:

```
stringr::str_extract(r'Lat(.*?)\,', y)
```

I get this error:

> `>Error: malformed raw string literal at line 1`

why?

Comment: Do you want `stringr::str_extract(y, 'Lat(.*?)\\,')
[1] "Lat 53.381 Lon -1.490,"`

Comment: If you use raw strings with `r'` then you need parentheses too: `r'(Lat(.*?)\,)'`. This is documented at `?Quotes`, *"Raw character constants are also available using a syntax similar to the one used in C++: `r"(...)"` with ... any character sequence, except that it must not contain the closing sequence `‘⁠)"⁠’`. The delimiter pairs `[]` and `{}` can also be used, and `R` can be used in place of `r`."*

Comment: ```str_match(y, r'(Lat([^\,]+))')[1]``` or ```stringr::str_extract(y, r'(Lat(.*?)\,)')```

Answer (score 2):

With R's raw strings (introduced in version 4.0.0), you need to use either `(` or `[` or `{` with the quotes, e.g.,

```
r'{Lat(.*?)\,}'
```

This is documented at `?Quotes` (and in the release notes):

> Raw character constants are also available using a syntax similar to the one used in C++: `r"(...)"` with `...` any character sequence, except that it must not contain the closing sequence `)"⁠`. The delimiter pairs `[]` and `{}` can also be used, and `R` can be used in place of `r`."